# Maven equivalent in .NET C#

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, maven, intellij-idea

Let's assume there are two Maven Java projects, A and B. A has a dependency on B. B is placed in remote Maven repository and also on GitHub.

In IntelliJ Idea IDE, I will open project A and also B (B is cloned from GitHub) in two separate windows.

Now, B has a class named `Car`. When I 'Ctrl+Left mouse button click' on class `Car` in project A, IDE switches me automatically to the source code in opened project B. Therefore I can comfortably work together on A and B.

How can I achieve same behaviour with .NET C# and Visual Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rough equivalent to Maven in the .NET ecosystem is [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/). NuGet files can be [created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) using the IDE or command-line tools such as [`dotnet pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x) or [`nuget pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference). A NuGet file is just a regular `.zip` file with the `.nupkg` extension. These files can be hosted on http://www.nuget.org for the general public to consume, on a site such as http://www.myget.org, or on a [private hosted NuGet server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview).

The NuGet tools also have the ability to [create debug symbol packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages) that contain the source code files. The debug symbol packages can be hosted on public or private symbol servers and [used in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/symbols/debug-with-symbols-visual-studio) to step through the code, with the configuration options enabled in Visual Studio.

If you open project A in Visual Studio and [automatic package restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) is enabled and that project has a [package reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) to project B, when you build the project it will automatically download the NuGet file for project B, unpack it to your local NuGet cache, and use the assembly for project B in your project.

If Visual Studio is [configured correctly to find a debug symbols package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger) corresponding to the exact version of project B, it will allow the debugger to step through the code of project B.

> AFAIK, opening the code file of project B and then setting a break point is not possible (someone leave a comment if this is wrong), you need to set a breakpoint in project A and then when you step into the line that calls/instantiates the `Car` class, Visual Studio will open up the code file so you can step through it.

#### Update 2023-01-15

Note that the above symbols documentation still works, but there is now a better way. If the author of a NuGet package configures [Source Link](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#source-link) and the code exists in a Git repository, an IDE can [enable source stepping](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/4.8.0-beta00016/api/core/source-stepping.html) and the code files can be downloaded directly from the repository into the IDE's debugger. This means it is no longer necessary to package source files in the symbols package. This feature uses a Git commit hash to ensure that the source code matches the binary even if you upgrade the NuGet package later.

The symbols have also been updated to allow a [`.snupkg` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg) by including `<PropertyGroup><IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols><SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat></PropertyGroup>` in the project file. This new format can be uploaded directly to NuGet instead of having to use a 3rd party symbol or self hosted server for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually it is possible. But some MSBuild modification is necessary.

Preconditions:

- use the new MSBuild format that was shiped with VS 2017

Step by step:

- create a solution and add both projects
- I assume project A has a package reference to project B and the nuget package names are the same as the project names
- in the root directory of both projects, which is probably not part of any source control system, create a file with the name Directory.Build.targets with the following content:

  true

  ```
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SolutionFileContent>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(SolutionPath)))</SolutionFileContent>
      <SmartSolutionDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName( $(SolutionPath) ))</SmartSolutionDir>
      <RegexPattern>(?&lt;="[PackageName]", ")(.*)(?=", ")</RegexPattern>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>

      <!-- Keep the identity of the  packagereference -->
      <SmartPackageReference Include="@(PackageReference)">
        <PackageName>%(Identity)</PackageName>
        <InSolution>$(SolutionFileContent.Contains('\%(Identity).csproj'))</InSolution>
      </SmartPackageReference>

      <!-- Filter them by mapping them to another itemGroup using the WithMetadataValue item function -->
      <PackageInSolution Include="@(SmartPackageReference -> WithMetadataValue('InSolution', True) )">
        <Pattern>$(RegexPattern.Replace('[PackageName]','%(PackageName)') )</Pattern>
        <SmartPath>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match( '$(SolutionFileContent)', '%(Pattern)' ))</SmartPath>
      </PackageInSolution>

      <ProjectReference  Include="@(PackageInSolution -> '$(SmartSolutionDir)\%(SmartPath)' )"/>

      <!-- Remove the package references that are now referenced as projects -->
      <PackageReference Remove="@(PackageInSolution -> '%(PackageName)' )"/>
    </ItemGroup>

  </When>
  ```

What happens here, is that all package references are automatically dynamically replaced with project references, when they are contained in the currently opened solution.

For further information, i have posted that solution also in a MSBuild github issue: 
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1151